# Is it possible to redirect to native settings pages for subscription management from React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to redirect to the subscription pages on React Native.

The code I've found online for how to do that is this:

```
Linking.openURL(
  "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"
);
```

For iOS

And this:

```
    Linking.openURL(
      "https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?package=YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME&sku=YOUR_PRODUCT_ID"
    );
```

For Android.

I can't test the Android link yet, as I do not have the relevant package name or product ID created yet, but I have tried the iOS link, and it does not redirect to the settings/subscription management page.

All I get is this error message with the iOS link (on a physical device - as well as in the simulator) - even though I am **absolutely** signed into my Apple accounts on the physical device:

```
pings metrics dialogIdMZFinance.ManageSubscriptionsLoginRequired messageSign in to manage subscri messageCode5074 options Manage Subscriptions CancelactionUrlbuy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptionseventTypedialog failureType5074 customerMessageSign in to manage subscriptions. m-allowed dialog kindauthorization m-allowed messageSign in to manage subscriptions.explanationEnter your Apple ID and password and click Manage Subscriptions.defaultButtonok okButtonStringManage Subscriptions okButtonActionkindGotourlhttps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/com.apple.jingle.app.finance.DirectAction/manageSubscriptionscancelButtonStringCancel initialCheckboxValue cancel-purchase-batch
```

I want users to be able to click a button and be sent to that page (in case they want to cancel a subscription).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: for android `https://play.google.com/store/account?utm_source=google&utm_medium=account&utm_campaign=my-account`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the new URL is

```
https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions
```

I will update when I have confirmed the Android link.

Comment: care to share android link please @Steven ?

Answer (score 0):

here is the Android Link to open subscription page of playstore

```
https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?package=com.yourpackagename
```